# Some ideal property in a local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> If we change the ideal $$(X_1,X_2^2-X_1,...,X^2_{n+1}-X_n,...)$$ to $$(X_1^2,X_2^2-X_1,...,X^2_{n+1}-X_n,...)$$ in [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711322/is-every-ideal-of-r-a-sum-of-a-nilpotent-ideal-and-an-idempotent-ideal/1713450#1713450), what is the answer to the raised question?

Again, the new local ring $R$ is of zero Krull dimension, and any ideal generated by a finite number of powers of $\bar X_i$'s is nilpotent.

Thanks for any cooperation!

Comment: Btw, the change you made doesn't change much the question. The relations $x_i^{2^{i-1}}=0$ are replaced by $x_i^{2^{i}}=0$, so I expect the same answer.

Comment: @user26857 What is an example of an ideal which is neither f.g. nor idempotent, please?